Error when testing media query styles with Jest and Styled-components
I am learning testing with Jest and Styled-components, and I encountered an error when testing the application of styles at the 'md' breakpoint. The test is failing to detect the max-width: 1440px style on the component. Here is my test code and the error message I'm receiving:
expect(container.firstChild).toHaveStyle("max-width: 1440px");
The error message is:
Expected: max-width: 1440px
Received: 
I'm using the @media(min-width: 768px) media query in the component's styles, and I’ve tried adjusting the test to simulate the screen size. However, the test still fails.
Can someone help me figure out how to correctly test media query styles in this case?"
